# Dreamweaver showing error with Javascript

Tags: jquery, dreamweaver

i have written a simple code of jQuery, and dreamweaver is giving syntax error at `</script>`.
Is there any modification or option which will make it work?

[image]

Comment: what error ? what code ? the code is in a separate file or in the html file ? need more precision about your poste...

Comment: I doubt it is about </script> tag. Perhaps you should check code before enclosing tag.

Comment: Added screenshot link

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, its sorted.. the issue was with the copy/paste...
some weird characters might have effected the code!